# Is this function transfering from contract address or from msg.sender?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

The basic idea is to have list of say 10 pre-approved addresses that can call this, but I'm trying to figure out if the balance will be deducted from their balances or from the contract? 10x!

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public onlyapprovedaddr returns (bool) 
{
    return super.transfer(_to, _value);

}
```

Comment: It all depends on the implemenation of `super.transfer`. Could you paste the source code of  any contracts the current contract inherits from that contain the function `transfer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're inheriting basicToken (zippelin) contract

where `transfer` function is defined as follow :

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

        // SafeMath.sub will throw if there is not enough balance.
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }
```

the sent amount would be deducted from the sender's (who called the function) balance

```
balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
```

Comment: thanks! I guess safemath will be optional here? I mean I'm not going to use the function exactly as above but yes I took it from zippelin!

Comment: it-s to avoid over/underflow